# Cocos2D infinite scrolling with finger gesture

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, scroll

Can I scroll left or right infinitely with a finger gesture (not parallax)? At the moment I am using CCCamera but seems like it doesn't good enough for what I need..

Are there any examples of it?

```
_________________________________

  1  |  2   |  3   |  4   |  1  |   
_________________________________
```

Answer (score 0):

Read my [article on scrolling with cocos2d](http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/2012/12/ways-scrolling-cocos2d-explained/). Specifically, don't use CCCamera unless you absolutely **have** to. The article explains why and what these reasons are.